# Specific traffic analysis

Tags: networking, traffic

In the recent days, my traffic increased rapidly. How can I check which application is responsible for that?

Answer (score 4):

ntop is a classic

Install

```
sudo apt-get install ntop
```

You will be asked to set a password during the install

point firefox to `http://localhost:3000` or `https://localhost:3001`

log in with the username `admin` and the password you set.

notp will show you all sorts of information.

Small sample:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I use `nethogs` ; it tells me the current usage and the processes:

> NetHogs is a small 'net top' tool. Instead of breaking the traffic
>   down per  protocol or per subnet, like most tools do, it groups
>   bandwidth by process.  NetHogs does not rely on a special kernel
>   module to be loaded. Homepage: http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/

It is available in the software center and repositories.

Answer (score 1):

tools like `iftop` are useful for seeing what's going on. You can link the flows to applications by looking at which programs have which ports open `netstat -ntp`

Answer (score 0):

Try darkstat as an alternative to ntop, it's much lighter on system resources (although not as pretty or featureful).