# Is it possible to view per-process statistics on traffic usage?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, internet, monitoring, traffic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specific traffic analysis](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90078/specific-traffic-analysis)

In bmon and vnstat I can see whole amount of received and sent traffic. But I can't see its origins (processes that sent those requests). Currently I see that during several last hours several GiBs of traffic was received by my computer but I have no idea which process(es) invoked receiving of such  amount of traffic. How can I debug it?